# Alexa Flash Briefing Error Parsing Feed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-flash-briefing-skill

I wrote a Alexa flash briefing and it has been running smoothly for the last few days. All of the sudden yesterday, my endpoint stopped being recognized. When I try to test the endpoint anywhere else, everything looks good.

*Just to make clear. This endpoint has been working for weeks without any issue up until yesterday.*

I wrote the endpoint in AWS lambda. Here is my response code in lamba.

```
callback(null, {
    statusCode: '200',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(
        {
            "uid": uuidv4(),
            "updateDate": new Date(),
            "titleText": "FILLER",
            "mainText": mainText})
        });
```

I understand the statusCode is not necessary for a flash briefing response, and I have tested with it removed and it does not change anything. I have also tried remove JSON.stringify and nothing changes. Has anything changed in what they expect in the response and simply did not update the information on the documentation? Did I remove something in IAM that is required? Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you edited your IAM? Sometimes when you remove a security rule from IAM then it stops the access to a particular application/resource.

Comment: I do not believe I did, I rarely go in there. Is there a rule I need in particular that I may have removed by accident?

Answer (score 0):

So I seemed to have fixed the issue. I created a new Lambda function, pasted my code in, and now it seems to be working. I believe the issue may have been with the API Gateway. I may have edited something which changed my gateway settings.